# cmake Run Command Before & After Sources are Compiled

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to use Android NDK's cmake to execute a command on the source files before any compilation occurs, and then another command after compilation occurs.

The command will basically run a script to  search-and-replace strings and then put them back after the build.

My current setup is

```
add_custom_command( TARGET native-lib
                    PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND <my-command>
                    )

add_custom_command( TARGET native-lib
                    POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND <my-command>
                    )
```

Unfortunately, `PRE_BUILD` means [Run before any other rules are executed within the target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html), so the sources have not actually been transported to the execution directory (`app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86/src/main/cpp/` in the case of NDK with Android Studio).

Is there a possibility to run a command **before** any compilation but **after** sources have been copied?

Comment: `The command will basically run a script to search-and-replace strings and then put them back after the build.` - Do you want to reverse content of the source files after their compilation? But after that the source files will be treated as **newer** than the library, so next build invocation will attempt to rebuild the library. Copiing files into "execution directory" should be treated by `CMakeLists.txt` script as *transparent*: if you want to modify sources, you should modify original sources, not a copied ones. Then original sources will be copied into execution directory.

Comment: BTW, according to [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) you refer to, on Android (and in any non-Visual Studio generator) `PRE_BUILD` is equal to `PRE_LINK`, so source files are already compiled at this step.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I'd like to have an intermediary step __before__ the compilation. Is there a build step that occurs right after cmake copies the files for compilation?

Comment: I meant, that you may use ["generating files" flow](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) of `add_cusom_command`. Like `add_custom_command(OUTPUT "source.c" DEPENDS "source.c.orig" COMMAND <my-command>)`. Then use *OUTPUT* of this command in `add_library` invocation: `add_library(<my-library> source.c ...)`. Not sure why you insist on changing only **copied files** - as I said before, copiing/non-copiing source files should be transparent for `CMakeLists.txt` script.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds alright. but I didn't get the `DEPENDS` argument. Is it possible to simply use `add_custom_command` and apply that on a `source.cpp` to generate a new `source_new.cpp` which one can use in `add_library`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Then my description maps to your approach by replacing `source.cpp` -> `source_new.cpp` and  `source.c.orig` -> `source.c`.

Comment: Is there a way to apply one command to an entire directory?

Comment: You may list **all files**, read by the `COMMAND`, in `DEPENDS` section, and all generated source files in `OUTPUT` section. Using `file(GLOB)` you can collect all files in a directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @Tsyvarev. Feel free to write this as an answer and I'll accept it